# SQL : join more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, relational-division

Write an sql query to select the names of the students who have attended all the lectures of professor 'JOHN' but not any lecture of professor 'JOSEPH'.

I have written this query, but it is giving me the name of student who are taking the lecture from joseph also.

```
select distinct s.studentname 
from Student s,Attendance a,Lecture l 
where s.StudentId=a.studid 
  and l.lecId = a.lectureid 
  and l.professor='JOHN' 
  and l.professor != 'JOSEPH';
```

I am making some error in above query but not able to identify the same.

here is the table structure

**Student table**

```
# StudentId, StudentName, Sex
'1', 'AMY', 'M'
'2', 'JACK', 'M'
'3', 'TONY', 'M'
'4', 'TARA', 'M'
'5', 'SARAH', 'F'
'6', 'TOM', 'F'
```

**Lecture Table**

```
# LecId, Subject, Professor
1, MATH, JOHN
2, MATH, JOSEPH
3, PHY, MARK
4, PHY, MAX
5, PHY, JOHN
6, CHEM, JOHN
7, CHEM, JOSEPH
8, HISTORY, JOSEPH
```

**Attendance table**

```
# StudId, LectureId
'1', '1'
'1', '2'
'3', '1'
'2', '5'
'2', '6'
'3', '4'
'1', '6'
'4', '5'
'5', '1'
'5', '2'
'1', '3'
'1', '4'
'1', '5'
'1', '6'
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in standard SQL in 1992. That was before MySQL was even invented! If you are attending a class or using a book or tutorial teaching you to use this ancient syntax, you should quit it. Use proper explicit joins instead (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look across all rows that belong to a given student, so a simple `where` clause cannot do what you want. Instead, you can use aggregation and filer with a `having` clause:

```
select s.studentname 
from student s
inner join attendance a on s.studentId = a.studid
inner join lecture l on l.lecId = a.lectureid 
group by s.studentId, s.studentname 
having max(l.professor= 'JOHN') = 1 and max(l.professor = 'JOSEPH') = 0
```

If you want teachers that addented *all* lectures of John and none of Joseph, then:

```
select s.studentname 
from student s
inner join attendance a on s.studentId = a.studid
inner join lecture l on l.lecId = a.lectureid 
group by s.studentId, s.studentname 
having 
    sum(l.professor= 'JOHN') = (select count(*) from lecture where professor = 'JOHN')
    and max(l.professor = 'JOSEPH') = 0
```

Comment: hey sorry, made a little change in question which will impact a lot .. extremely sorry , could you please help me now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from Student st
where exists(select * from Lecture l
             join Attendance a
             on l.LecId = a.LectureId
             where l.Professor = 'John'
             and a.StudId = st.StudentId)
and exists(select * from Lecture l
               join Attendance a
               on l.LecId = a.LectureId
               where l.Professor = 'Joseph'
               and a.StudId = st.StudentId)
```

Comment: @sparsh610 Could you please add DDL so I can test it? Also, Tony also fulfilles requirements. What is your current result?

Comment: how to get that in mysql ?

Comment: Just put data in http://sqlfiddle.com and share the link

Comment: hey sorry, made a little change in question which will impact a lot .. extremely sorry , could you please help me now :)

Comment: @sparsh610 Try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you MySQL version support GROUP_CONCAT, you can try this below script-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39e17f77f3d695371fc5d961c0a0d7a4)

```
SELECT S.StudentId,S.StudentName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT L.Professor)
FROM Attendance A
INNER JOIN Lecture L ON A.LectureId = L.LecId
INNER JOIN Student S ON A.StudId = S.StudentId
GROUP BY S.StudentId,S.StudentName
HAVING  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT L.Professor) = 'JOHN'
```

This above query will return student list that only taking course from 'JOHN'. No one else.

But if your requirement changed to add more professors in the list, you can add Professors name accordingly in the HAVING clause checking. But you need to apply a appropriate ordering that case.

Comment: close enogh, but why it not giving the name of JACK, studid : 2 , he is also attending only JOHN

Comment: Yes, 2 should be there, Checking

Comment: Changed a bit @sparsh610 please check

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.StudentName 
from Student s
inner join Attendance a on s.StudentId = a.StudId
inner join Lecture l on l.LecId = a.LectureId 
group by s.StudentId, s.StudentName 
having 
    sum(l.Professor= 'JOHN') = (select count(*) from lecture where Professor = 'JOHN')
    and max(l.Professor = 'JOSEPH') = 0
order by s.StudentName
```

#asked in interview (MakeMyTrip)

Comment: Thank you for adding to the list of answers. While some may be able to immediately understand what you've shared, others may not. It will is more helpful to add at least a little context in addition to the code.

Answer (score -1):

I re-phrased the join you did... but it seemed to work.

Does this query return the data set you are looking for?

```
SELECT s.studentname, l.Subject, l.Professor
FROM Student s JOIN Attendance a
ON s.StudentId = a.StudId
JOIN Lecture l 
ON l.lecId = a.lectureid
WHERE l.professor='JOHN' 
  AND l.professor != 'JOSEPH';
```

Answer (score -1):

MSSQL:

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT StudentName, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(
        PARTITION BY studid
        ORDER BY studid
    ) cou 
    FROM attendance a,lecture l,student s 
    WHERE a.LectureId = l.LecId
    AND a.StudId = s.StudentId
    AND l.Professor = 'john'
)
SELECT StudentName
FROM cte
WHERE cou = 3

Except

SELECT StudentName
FROM attendance a, lecture l, student s 
WHERE a.LectureId = l.LecId
AND a.StudId = s.StudentId
AND l.Professor = 'joseph'
```

Comment: I'm using partitionby on studid and fetching students who attended all three classes of john(condition on where clause). i use cou=3 to grab students who attended all 3 classes of john. In the next step, I'm using except on a table where students attended joseph's class with the cte table. here i get desired output, table a excludes stdname that are present in table b.